# Bound columns require a field or property access expression in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have relations one to many in DB ( i used entity interface to generate associations between 2 obj)
Im getting error:
Bound columns require a field or property access expression

My code:

in view:

```
  Html.Telerik()
        .Grid<Y.Orders.Models.Orders>("orders")

        .Name("Orders")
        .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.Id))
        //.Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(20).Style(GridPagerStyles.PageSizeDropDown | GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Custom("comments").ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text).Text("Szczegóły").Action("Index", "Komentarze");
            });
            columns.Bound(o => o.Tytul).Title("Title");
            columns.Bound(o => o.Deliveries.Sum(m=>m.deliveryTime)).Title("Time of order");
        })
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable(sort =>
        {
            sort.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn); sort.OrderBy(ord =>
            {
                ord.Add(o => o.Time).Descending();

            });
        })
        .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Groups(groups =>
        {
            groups.Add(c => c.Users.Firms.Name);
        }))
        .Render();
```

in entity model:

```
    public ObjectSet<Deliveries>  Deliveries
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_ Deliveries
 == null))
                {
                    _Deliveries = base.CreateObjectSet<Deliveries>("Deliveries");
                }
                return _Deliveries;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Deliveries> _Deliveries;
```

In deliveries i havnt any null.

Where is problem ?

Answer (score 11):

columns.Bound accept only primitive as int or string.
You can't aggregate or transform object as your example :

```
o.Deliveries.Sum(m=>m.deliveryTime)
```

You do create in `Deliveries` object a parameter as this :

```
public int SumDeliveries 
{
  get { return this.Sum(m=>m.deliveryTime); }
}
```

and so you can bind this on grid.

Comment: You mean editing the model class `partial` and adding a new field as a c# property